# Is there a way we can write mongodb aggregation pipeline by customizing services in feathers js

Tags: feathersjs

Can anyone provide basic examples of how to customize a feathers service to perform mongodb aggregation pipeline? I have tried it with hooks but I lost in the midway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `Custom Service` in FeathersJs where in the class you can use aggregation or also in hooks you can use it.

EX :
    I have service users I want to get data through aggregation.

```
const userData = context.app.service('users').Model.aggregate([
    // Use Your pipelines here
]);
```